# Accessing Proxy over HTTPS doesnt work

Tags: sockets, ssl, https, proxy, webserver

created a webserver(http port 80, https:443) and proxy server(http 8080,https:8081) 
 am seeing issue when I access proxy over https like

```
https://xyz:8081/
```

wireshark shows client(fireforx or chrome) is sending certificate data in HTTP packet , I see certificate text .

Any idea what could be wrong ? browser says no data received
If TLS session is already established(https webserver) would another TLS sessions is created if I try to access https proxy ?

I created SSL socket like
ctx_init
put the socket on select and did accept/sslaccept once I get
and then did SSL_Read

NB: Rest all access like http/https to webserver or http to proxy server works fine.

**Updates**: Issue was client was sending fragmented HTTP request 
So for a GET request it was sent by client like this
Packet 1 was GE
Packet 2 was rest T ....\r\n\r\n 
So in code I have to collect until until full HTTP packet is received

Comment: What does your "HTTPS proxy" do? Proxying of HTTPS connections is done by supporting CONNECT verb in the proxy and building an opaque tunnel. This is completely different from HTTP proxy .

Comment: same like HTTP proxy ..yes I am supporting CONNECT, i.e. if I recv GET request , I first did a CONNECT and then just pass data across.problem is I am not getting any packet at all in SSL_read function of https proxy...rcv_count is coming to 0 sometime I see EPIPE or EWOULDBLOCK error

Comment: It seems that you don't understand how HTTPS proxy works. It's NOT the same as HTTP Proxy, and that's why it doesn't work like you expect. You need to read how HTTPS proxies are made.

Comment: KIndly suggest some good  document to read about https proxy , many thanks !

Comment: Please check the introductory article on https://www.eldos.com/security/articles/7926.php

Comment: Thanks let me go through it

Comment: Another general question would browser do TLS handshake again for each https port ? For example my webserver is listening https socks on 443 and 8080 , so would it do SSL handshake again if I try to connect via 8080 ? or would it use existing tunnel created earlier for 443 ?

Comment: The endpoint is identified by the address and port. Connecting to different port mean connecting to different endpoint. The handshake should be performed from scratch - that's a different resource there.